# Align: Numbering with an own counter

Tags: align, counters

I have a document where I use chapters and sections. E.g. there is >>Definition 4.1.13<<.
Now I want to use a counter for align-environments. But when I use it, I get

Definition 4.1.13: We want to show the equations

1+2 = 3         (4.1)

and

2+3 = 5         (4.2).

But I want the counter to be consecutive in the whole document, starting by (1). So my result shall be:

Definition 4.1.13: We want to show the equations

1+2 = 3         (1)

and

2+3 = 5         (2).

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[ngerman, fontsize=11pt, DIV=12 ,BCOR = 10mm, parskip=half-, twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
        \section{Section 1}
            We want to show something, namely:
                \begin{align}
                    1+2 = 3
                \end{align}
            and
                \begin{align}
                    2+3 = 5
                \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}` should do the trick.

Comment: Unrelated, you should not use `align` for oneliners. The trained eye can often tell the difference between it and using `equation` for oneliners.

Comment: @daleif: It does the trick. Thank you for both very helpful comments. If you would post it as an answer, I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to implementing @daleif's suggestion of executing `\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}`, you should also break your apparent bad habit of using `align` environments for single-row numbered displayed equations. Do yourself a big favor and start using `equation` environments instead. You'll save a lot of vertical whitespace by making the switch. Just compare the vertical distance between the first pair of horizontal rules with the distance of the second pair. Can you guess which pair encases two `align` environments instead of two `equation` environments?

[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman, fontsize=11pt, DIV=12,
     BCOR = 10mm, parskip=half-, twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}

\begin{document}

We want to show something:
\hrule
    \begin{align}
        1+2 = 3
    \end{align}
and
    \begin{align}
        2+3 = 5
    \end{align}
\hrule

\bigskip
We want to show something:
\hrule
    \begin{equation}
        1+2 = 3
    \end{equation}
and
    \begin{equation}
        2+3 = 5
    \end{equation}
\hrule
\end{document}
```